# Why does this query throw ORA-00942 on 10g while it works on 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I execute this query without problem on my 11g installation :

```
SELECT
    PRODUCT_INFOS_idm.FIELD_VALUE "mother_id",
    PRODUCT_INFOS_ep.FIELD_VALUE "product_thickness",
    COIL_INFOS.TIME_STAMP,
    COIL_INFOS.IN_THICKNESS,
    COIL_INFOS.MEASURED_LENGTH,
    COIL_INFOS.MEASURED_WIDTH,
    COIL_INFOS.PARAM_SET_TOP_SIDE,
    COIL_INFOS.PARAM_SET_BOTTOM_SIDE
FROM
    COIL_INFOS
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCT_INFOS PRODUCT_INFOS_idm
    on PRODUCT_INFOS_idm.COIL_ID_SYSTEM=COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM
    and PRODUCT_INFOS_idm.TIME_STAMP=COIL_INFOS.TIME_STAMP
    and PRODUCT_INFOS_idm.FIELD_NAME='ID bobina'
INNER JOIN  
    PRODUCT_INFOS PRODUCT_INFOS_ep
    on PRODUCT_INFOS_ep.COIL_ID_SYSTEM=COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM
    and PRODUCT_INFOS_ep.TIME_STAMP=COIL_INFOS.TIME_STAMP
    and PRODUCT_INFOS_ep.FIELD_NAME='Anchura'
WHERE
    (COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM LIKE '14051800' OR COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID LIKE '14051800')
```

But when my customer (who may have a 10g installation) executes it, he gets

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

**Other queries show that he has the same tables and columns.** The following queries executes without problem :

```
select count(*) from COIL_INFOS
select count(*) from PRODUCT_INFOS
```

What can be the problem ? Is there a syntax error somewhere ? I suspect there is a problem with the Oracle version (I already had to remove the "as" I usually use for column aliasing). Does Oracle 10g support table aliasing ?

Comment: Apparently one table (or view or synonym) was not created in the environment of your customer.

Comment: Is he executing it on the right database?

Comment: Double-check the schema of the user used to connect to the database. It does seem like a table is missing.

Comment: Maybe it is the duplicated table names, PRODUCT_INFOS

Comment: @davidkonrad I give aliases to the tables. Don't 10g support them ?

Comment: So make sure that all of the tables mentioned in the query exist...

Comment: It is not relevant to your question, but it is worth mentioning that implict joins are 20 years out of date and there are [numerous reasons](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) to start using explicit joins, so I thought I'd share my 2 pennies.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks. I won't use that right now as I'm only focusing on compatibility with my specific customer but I'll probably take the next opportunity to use explicit joins in this application.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I verified that this isn't a problem of table (or view) missing. See edited question.

Comment: You've tagged this as JDBC, so is the customer only executing it from a Java app, or have they tried it directly in the database? Is JDBC connecting with the same credentials they're able to do the `count(*)` with?

Comment: The same problem occurs when the query is executed by my customer using Microsoft Query.

Comment: But can the customer run select count(\*) on either table through Microsoft Query *using the same credentials*?

Comment: Yes, the credentials are the same (I don't know any other account)

Comment: It strikes me we had a problem like this when we were on 10g (flaky, IMHO - YMMV), and the problem turned out to be a bug that needed to be patched.  Give your DBA a six-pack of donuts (DBA's work best when properly fueled - and the proper fuel for a DBA is donuts - chocolate covered, for preference :-), and send him/her/it off to search through the 10g bug database.  No guarantees, but it sure sounds awfully familiar...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In my case, the lack of DBA at this customer is the reason of many of my torments...

Comment: As I wasn't clear enough on this question, it didn't turn well. So I asked [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117528/0ra-00952-on-inner-join-with-oracle-10g/13118722#13118722) with more precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was hinted by Bob in comments, the problem was due to a bad version of Oracle 10g.

There are a few servers on which the same schema and the same query are used, only the one with version 10.2.0.1.0 had the problem. Oracle experts think the bug doesn't exist on 10.2.0.4 but I have no access to Oracle bug database.

As patching the server was out of question for our customer, we finally got around the bug by creating a view for this query.

TLDR : when Oracle says a version is buggy and should not be used, it should not be used.

Answer (score 5):

There are several reasons why we might get ORA-00942.

1. The most obvious one is, the table does not exist in the database.  That's easy enough to check in the data dictionary views, such as DBA_TABLES.
2. The table exists but we are referencing it wrongly.  The common scenario is when the table was created with a mixed-case name in double quotes; when this happens we always have to refer to the table name with a mixed-case name in double quotes, because `EMPLOYEES != "Employees"`.
3. The table is owned by a different user and our code doesn't include the schema name when we call it (and we don't have a synonym either).
4. The table is owned by a different user and that user hasn't granted us privileges on it.
5. The table is owned by a different user and that user has granted us privileges on it through a role but we want to reference it in a stored procedure or a view.  In this situation we must have the privileges granted to our user directly, because the Oracle Security model works that way.

Given that you say "Other queries show that he has the same tables and columns" we can rule out the first option, and probably the second one.  So it's most likely a  problem with a missing synonym or missing permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with Oracle version. You are using standard queries that will work in even older version of Oracle than 10.

I suspect one or more of the following will be true:

- you may have synonyms in your 11g database but not in 10g at the client.
- The client is using different credentials to test select count(*) from table than that used to run the query.