# 0RA-00952 on inner join with Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

This works :

```
SELECT
     PRODUCT_INFOS.FIELD_VALUE,
     PRODUCT_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM,
     PRODUCT_INFOS.TIME_STAMP,
     PRODUCT_INFOS.FIELD_NAME
FROM
     PRODUCT_INFOS
```

This works :

```
SELECT
     COIL_INFOS.TIME_STAMP,
     COIL_INFOS.IN_THICKNESS,
     COIL_INFOS.MEASURED_LENGTH,
     COIL_INFOS.MEASURED_WIDTH,
     COIL_INFOS.PARAM_SET_TOP_SIDE,
     COIL_INFOS.PARAM_SET_BOTTOM_SIDE,
     COIL_INFOS.TIME_STAMP,
     COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM
FROM
     COIL_INFOS
WHERE
     (COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM LIKE '14051800' OR COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID LIKE '14051800')
```

This works on Oracle 11g but fails with `0RA-00952 - Table or view does not exist` on 10g (version 10.2.0) :

```
SELECT
     PRODUCT_INFOS.FIELD_VALUE,
     COIL_INFOS.TIME_STAMP,
     COIL_INFOS.IN_THICKNESS,
     COIL_INFOS.MEASURED_LENGTH,
     COIL_INFOS.MEASURED_WIDTH,
     COIL_INFOS.PARAM_SET_TOP_SIDE,
     COIL_INFOS.PARAM_SET_BOTTOM_SIDE
FROM
     COIL_INFOS
INNER JOIN
     PRODUCT_INFOS
     on PRODUCT_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM=COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM
     and PRODUCT_INFOS.TIME_STAMP=COIL_INFOS.TIME_STAMP
     and PRODUCT_INFOS.FIELD_NAME='ID bobina'
WHERE
     (COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM LIKE '14051800' OR COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID
LIKE '14051800')
```

I see no other difference than the version of Oracle (the bases are created using the same dump). As I suspect a bug in Oracle 10g, I'd accept as answer a bug report clearly related to the problem.

Of course a direct solution or a workaround would be accepted too.

Comment: Could it be something related to the schema which owns the tables versus default schema? For the query which doesnt work on 10G, have you tried paring it down to one table to isolate which table is causing the error? I use 10G and 11G all the time and I have yet to run across any such issue with `Inner Join` per se

Comment: @InSane I thought this was exactly what I did : I cut the query in two queries to check this problem occurs only on join (in fact I prepared a dozen queries and asked my customer to run them). Can it be a very precise version of 10g causing the problem ? I know this can't be a general problem of Joins (it would not have passed Oracle's tests) but I can't find what is specific or unusual in my query.

Comment: It is all very odd. I must admit I cannot find any problem with your query per se either. Seems straight forward enough that it doesnt make any sense as to why it doesnt work. If you can share your schema, i wouldnt mind running it on my 10G instance to give it a whirl.

Comment: The query is seen as OK by most server (it is generic and used on 11g, Sybase and MsSQL servers since a long time). I just bang my head on this as I'm trying to let my customer deploy my application...

Comment: @dystroy - Did you try explicitly prepending the table owner(s) to you statement?

Comment: Yes. It failed in the same manner (in fact that was the initial version before I tried to strip the queries to the minimal version while searching for the problem).

Comment: Wild guess: do you have a schema named PRODUCT_INFOS or COIL_INFOS on the customer's database?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I hope not but I can't exclude it. How would you test this hypothesis with a query not requiring special rights ?

Comment: select * from all_users should return all user names on the database - check whether this contains PRODUCT_INFOS or COIL_INFOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I won't accept my own answer fast. Feel free to submit a more precise one, especially if you found a public bug report from Oracle.*

I found a workaround :

```
SELECT
     PRODUCT_INFOS.FIELD_VALUE,
     COIL_INFOS.TIME_STAMP,
     COIL_INFOS.IN_THICKNESS,
     COIL_INFOS.MEASURED_LENGTH,
     COIL_INFOS.MEASURED_WIDTH,
     COIL_INFOS.PARAM_SET_TOP_SIDE,
     COIL_INFOS.PARAM_SET_BOTTOM_SIDE
FROM
     COIL_INFOS, PRODUCT_INFOS
WHERE
     PRODUCT_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM=COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM
     and PRODUCT_INFOS.TIME_STAMP=COIL_INFOS.TIME_STAMP
     and PRODUCT_INFOS.FIELD_NAME='ID bobina'
     and (COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID_SYSTEM LIKE '14051800' OR COIL_INFOS.COIL_ID
LIKE '14051800')
```

This simplified syntax for the same query does work on the 10g server. I'm more on more on the opinion the used 10g version is buggy.

Comment: You've done your homework but it would be hard to believe that Oracle would fail for such basic functionality in whatever version/setup/scenario possible. +1 On the research, I'd love to know how this plays out.

Comment: @Lieven I agree with you but some other guy suggested to me that a similar problem was fixed by applying a patch on his 10g server. The fact that Oracle's bug database isn't public doesn't help, though.